# can I trust mysql_insert_id() to return correct value, multithreading paranoia

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multithreading, mysql-insert-id

I made a function that inserts a new line into a table, after calling an `INSERT` statement into mysql, I then make some checks, and then I check the value of `mysql_insert_id()`.

I want to be quiet knowing that *it is not possible for another thread to break in, inserting a row, before I get the result of `mysql_insert_id()`*.

My bet is that it should be safe, but I am asking because this one can be disastrous.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618047/can-you-trust-mysql-insert-id?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920804/mysql-insert-id-issue-in-concurrency-data-inserting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`manual`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that
>   client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
>   that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the
>   activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or
>   transactions.

So if your threads will use separate connections, they will get different insert IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. If mysql_insert_id() could be affected by other almost simultaneous hits to the same PHP script it would be useless.

It works on a per-connection basis.